# What was in the suitcase that the new Extremis recruit dropped in Iron Man 3?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-3

In Iron Man 3, about 25 minutes into the movie, one of Aldrich Killian's henchman walks over to a guy, and asks,

> "Can you regulate?".

Then Happy Hogan bumps into the person who was asked, making him drop the suitcase. Out of the suitcase drops a bunch of silvery metal things, that look sort of like dogtags. What were those things, and why did the guy want them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They were vials of the Extremis drug.  The guy injected himself, couldn't "regulate" the effect, and then exploded, being turned into a bomb.

Comment: Does the drug need to be injected multiple times then?

Comment: @higgs241 no, only once i believe.  i think they were selling it as a drug to create the bombs.

Comment: Well, to be fair, I'm pretty sure they deliberately over-dosed him, to turn him into an unwitting bomb.  That is, he actually _could_ regulate... And he was supposed to be one of the original soldiers, I think; so they weren't really selling it to just random people.

Answer (score 0):

The Extremis formula was designed to "upgrade" people's DNA and make them super human. Unfortunately, the formula has a kind of addictive effect on some people and they take too much too quickly and they turn themselves into a bomb.

Aldrich Killian needed to cover his tracks when these explosions occured, so he created The Manderin to explain them.

Comment: This is a good recap of Killian's general plan, but you might want to elaborate in which way it answers the actual question asked here.